# Access user signatures from within Outlook Add-In

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to build an Outlook Add-In using javascript. I couldn't find a way to retrieve the current user's signatures. I need that in order to insert the propper signature according to the selected FROM email (which the user controls while composing a message). Any clues?

Comment: In case you would stick to the "old" VBA approach, have a look at [QuoteFixMacro](https://macros4outlook.github.io/quotefixmacro/), which uses placeholders in the signature to put proper greeting (according to configuration). It could be enhanced to put defined signatures -- or the code could be modified to just replace "%SIGNATURE%" by defined content. -- Maybe setting `%SIGNATURE%` as your signature and then replacing that string could be the easiest solution for your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently getting user's signatures in an add-in is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there.

Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process. https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins

Comment: That site is no longer there, but I used a different one that was suggested on another post: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/allow-setting-user-signature-in-outlook-from-add-in/idi-p/3596992. Please make the Add-in API better. In general, not on request. I just want to have access to the available functions in Outlook.